# PHP while loop output to variables

Tags: php

I have the following loop to get data from a database...

```
$query = "SELECT id, metal, colour, value FROM data WHERE asset='gold' OR asset='silver' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $row['metal'] . " is " . $row["colour"] . "<br />";
    echo $row['metal'] . " is worth " . $row["value"] . "<br />";
}
```

which outputs the following:

```
silver is grey
silver is worth 50
gold is yellow
gold is worth 100
```

The following:

```
echo $row['metal'] . " is " .
```

and...

```
echo $row['metal'] . " is worth " .
```

...are simply there for testing and to help explain my issue. How would I go about putting the output into variables like so:

```
$silverColour = grey
$silverValue = 50
$goldColour = yellow
$goldValue = 100
```

Many Thanks

Comment: If I understand your question you are looking for something like $silverColour = $row['colour']; Is that correct?

Comment: I recomend you using objects for this kind of data movement...

Comment: mrpotocnik, yes correct :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your code this way:

```
$values = [];
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo $row['metal'] . " is " . $row["colour"] . "<br />";
    echo $row['metal'] . " is worth " . $row["value"] . "<br />";
    $values[$row['metal']] = $row;
}
```

Then you can access the values in the `$values` array:

```
echo '$silverColour = '. $values['silver']['colour'];
echo '$silverValue = '. $values['silver']['value'];
echo '$goldColour = '. $values['gold']['colour'];
echo '$goldValue = '. $values['gold']['value'];
```

Comment: Thank you to all who answered, I chose this as the answer as it was the first one I tried and it worked perfectly. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `{}`, try this:

```
  ${$row['metal'].'Color'} = $row["colour"]; 
  ${$row['metal'].'Value'}= $row["value"];
```

Another easier way is to use keys and values of arrays. Keep the key as

```
 $array[row['metal'].'Color']= $row["colour"];
 $array[row['metal'].'Value']= $row["value"];
```

Iterate over the array and print/access the values.

Comment: While this answer is flawless answering the question, in my honest opinion *variable variables* is not the way to go as it could create undesired variable names, meaning bugs in code.

Comment: @Xorifelse agreed. The approach needs to be changed, I answered him as per question.

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT id, metal, colour, value FROM data WHERE asset='gold' OR asset='silver' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
 ${$row['metal'].'color'} = $row['metal'];
 ${$row['metal'].'value'} = $row['value'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I *could* show you a hackish way of doing it, but I'd like to show you a different approach using arrays:

```
$query = "SELECT id, metal, colour, value FROM data WHERE asset='gold' OR asset='silver' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
$metals = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $metals[$row['metal']] = array('color' => $row['color'], 'value' => $row['value']);
}
```

After this, you'll have a nice array of all metals (`var_dump($metals);`).

Accessing it like this:

```
$metals['gold']['color'];
$metals['gold']['value'];
```

If you really insist on using your approach,

```
$query = "SELECT id, metal, colour, value FROM data WHERE asset='gold' OR asset='silver' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    ${$row['metal'] . 'Color' } = $row['color'];
    ${$row['metal'] . 'Value' } = $row['value'];
}
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$color= array();
$values= array();
while (($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   $color[] = (string) $row["colour"];
   $color[] = (string) $row["value"];
}

// If you don't want an array, but a string instead, use implode:

$color= implode(' ', $color)
$values= implode(' ', $values)
```